# What the best formula to pull only certain word, which is "Mojokerto"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this text in cell B2, and B3

Jl. Raya By Pass, Mergelo, Kedundung, Kec. Magersari, Kota Mojokerto,
Jawa Timur 61300

Jl. R.A Basuni No.58, Mergelo, Sooko, Kec. Sooko,
Kabupaten Mojokerto, Jawa Timur 61361

I want to pull only after word "Kota" or "Kabupaten".. or before "jawa timur".. so the result is "Mojokerto".

I use this formula =RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-SEARCH(", kota",B2)) but it only pull text after "kota" but not for text after "kabupaten", how to pull word after "kabupaten" also ya ?

Thanks

Comment: Use a wildcard so ", *k*a" may work - you can test that though.

Comment: Would it always only be a single word? Or can there be more words between for example "Kota Word1 Word2 Word3, Jawa Timur"?

Comment: replying JvdV: only single word,, example : "Mojokerto"